# Every time I build Unity application in Xcode for iOS, it creates a new icon

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, xcodebuild

I'm very new to developing for iOS. But I noticed that every time I make changes in unity and make a build to build it to Xcode project and then build and run it on my iPhone it keeps adding a new icon on my phone. How can I change it so that it rebuilds and deploys the app and updates the old one that was already installed, instead of adding bunch of the same icons to my phone? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience in developing with both Xcode and Unity, and as far as I know, it is not possible.

The reason being is that when developing with Xcode natively, any changes made to the project is still part of that specific project, and Xcode would treat it as a new version of the same project, and hence replace the old icon/app with the new one.

Unity however does it differently, every time Unity builds to Xcode, it essentially creates a completely new Xcode project. Despite the fact that Unity knows, just like Xcode in the previous case, that you had just made changes to the same project, Xcode, which is the one that's actually doing the building and deploying process, does not know this. All Xcode knows is that a new project was created by Unity, and it would build that, it does not know whether the current project has any correlation with the last one on the phone/simulator, since the older version is in another separate project of its own.

For my development, I just delete the old version of the app from the phone/simulator, there isn't really another way to do this.

Comment: Well I kinda solved it. Now it reinstalls the same app every time instead of creating a new one. First time I build in Xcode, next time I just hit build and run in Unity. It just overwrites old build folder as I understand. It just that every time I do that, it launches new Xcode app, but other than that, it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you set your app icons Unity or Xcode?. Better option set in Unity itself so all asset will manage unity.

Comment: I think I set it in Xcode. I haven't touched any settings so it must be default. I will have to look into that